# Quarkus Security Client Certificate in header fields

Tags: java, security, ssl, quarkus, client-certificates

I'm working on a very simple REST API using the Quarkus framework. I'd like to use client authentication, but after a few tries I eventually found the what I'm trying to achieve doesn't seem possible out of the box.

The API is dockerized and published on an azure app service environment. Unfortunately, I can't get the azure load balancer to talk to my app via SSL. Azure App Services passes the client certificate as a base64 payload in a header field dubbed X-ARR-ClientCert.

Maybe I'm missing some very important piece of knowledge here. Is there any way to leverage the TrustStore and Trust / accept the client certificate straight from the header field?
Should I implement my own Security Identity Provider for doing so

- extracting the Certificate from the header
- create a Security Identity instance

Comment: Did you tried to just use custom truststore with `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=path/to/custom/truststore.jks` ?

Comment: I did, but the communnication between App Service Load Balancer and the container is not in SSL :(